# Distutils - Where Am I going wrong?

Tags: python, distutils

I wanted to learn how to create python packages, so I visited http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html.

For this exercise I'm using Python 2.6.2 on Windows XP.

I followed along with the simple example and created a small test project:

```
person/

    setup.py

    person/
       __init__.py
       person.py
```

My person.py file is simple:

```
class Person(object):   
    def __init__(self, name="", age=0):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def sound_off(self):
        print "%s %d" % (self.name, self.age)
```

And my setup.py file is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='person',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['person'],
    )
```

I ran python setup.py sdist and it created MANIFEST, dist/ and build/.  Next I ran python setup.py install and it installed it to my site packages directory.

I run the python console and can import the person module, but I cannot import the Person class.

```
>>>import person
>>>from person import Person
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name Person
```

I checked the files added to site-packages and checked the sys.path in the console, they seem ok.  Why can't I import the Person class.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I think you'd need to do: `from person.person import Person`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
person/
   __init__.py
   person.py
```

You've got a package called `person`, and a module inside it called `person.person`. You defined the class in that module, so to access it you'd have to say:

```
import person.person
p= person.person.Person('Tim', 42)
```

If you want to put members directly inside the package `person`, you'd put them in the `__init__.py` file.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't really about distutils packages, but about Python packages -- a related *but different* thing with the same name. Packages in Python are a separate kind of module, that are directories with an `__init__.py` file. You created a `person` package with a `person` module with a `Person` class. `import person` gives you the package. If you want the `person` module *inside* the `person` package, you need `import person.person`. And if you want the `Person` class inside the `person` module inside the `person` package, you need `from person.person import Person`.

These things get a lot more obvious when you don't give different things the same name, and also when you don't put classes in separate modules for their own sake. Also see [Should I create each class in its own .py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098088/should-i-create-each-class-in-its-own-py-file)